# How to stop django postgresql timestramp conversion

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-rest-framework, django-views

When I Insert timestamp into Postgres table in EST (2019-02-21 05:37:46) and in Postgresql table is stores in IST (2019-02-21 16:07:46). I want time to be stored only in EST. Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: What are your settings for `USE_TZ` and `TIME_ZONE`? Read up [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/timezones/) to understand how Django uses time zones. Note that your db timestamp is still the correct time and when fetching it it will reflect the correct time in the user's time zone.

Comment: Also you should *not want to store only in EST*. You're using PostgreSQL and you should store in UTC time. That's because in the EST time zone there is daylight saving time (DST) in the summer, so you could get buggy behaviour when the time jumps (especially since there is an overlap of one hour when the clock goes back). The fact that a direct query gives you the timestamp back in IST does not mean the time is stored in IST, it's stored in UTC. It's showing IST probably because it's hosted on a server in IST time zone.

Comment: @dirkgroten so, when I ingest EST time to Postgres, It stores as UTC correct?
In my settings.py:
TIME_ZONE = 'EST'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = False

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to set `USE_TZ` to `False` when using Postgresql, because it's timezone aware by default. You run the risk of not passing the timezone correctly and saving the wrong time (if you pass a naive datetime to postgres, it'll assume it's UTC). I would switch to True if I were you. And yes, it stores correctly as UTC if you give it an aware datetime object. See [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects)

Comment: okay thanks for your information @dirkgroten

Answer (score 1):

In postgres, you can change the default format mask for **datetimes** using the set n postgres, you can change the default format mask for datetimes using the set **datestyle**

for more details follow this [link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/datatype-datetime.html)

also refer this [link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-formatting.html)

To my knowledge, there is no setting in PostgreSQL that would trim seconds from timestamp literals by default

Answer (score 0):

In general you should handle all datetimes in UTC, because these are absolute timestamps that are always correct. Even if you are only going to have users in the EST time zone use your website, the EST time zone has daylight saving time (DST) in the summer, so you could get buggy behaviour when the time jumps (especially since there is an overlap of one hour when the clock goes back). This means:

- Your code should use UTC timestamps to make calculations and pass around
- Your database should store UTC datetime (which PostgreSQL does anyway).

You should only transform to a local time zone when presenting the data to the user. This is default behaviour in Django:

- `USE_TZ = True` by default
- `TIME_ZONE = "America/New_York"` to set default time zone, which will take into account DST

So when you're saving a time-aware datetime to the database (in EST say), the database stores it as UTC. When you fetch and display it, Django will show it in the current time zone of the user (EST in your case). When you query the database directly using a tool, PostgreSQL gives back the UTC, correct datetime, but your shell or tool might display it in the local time zone. You can format your query to use a different time zone using the links posted by @c.grey in the other answer.

Read up on the details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/timezones/#time-zones)